# write KVLequations with subscripts neatly

Tags: subscripts

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
\textit{v}_{{}_{RZ}}=L\frac{di_{R}}{dt}+Ri_{R}+e_{R}+v_{XZ};
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:5}
\textit{v}_{YZ}=L\frac{di_{Y}}{dt}+Ri_{Y}+e_{Y}+v_{XZ};
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:6}
v_{BZ}=L\frac{di_{B}}{dt}+Ri_{B}+e_{B}+v_{XZ};
\end{equation}
```

[image: giving this output.but I would like to get better output][image: this is good in font]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You probably want to use the `align` environment of `amsmath`.

Comment: To the guys (and gals?) who are considering closing this posting: Please see my new answer and decide if I may have just guessed correctly what the OP was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: If your answer stops people from answering, then fine!

Comment: @Mico I'm sure that you have answered the question (so I marked it +1) but I am not sure that the OP will mark it as correct as they haven't been been since June 26, so I will vote to close...

Comment: @Andrew - Thanks for the upvote. :-) Let's hope that the OP comes back and provides some more information as to what his/her formatting objectives may be.

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want to fix. Going by the fact that you've posted two screenshots, I'm assuming that you wish to approximate some of the characteristics of the second screenshot (the one without equation numbers) with your own code.

- First off, it would appear that you're using `\textit{v}` as a cumbersome substitute for `\nu` (the lowercase Greek "nu"). The use of a double subscript in `\textit{v}_{{}_{RZ}}` also doesn't seem right; try `\nu_{RZ}` instead.
- It may also be the case that you wish to place all subscripts a bit deeper than the default amount below the respective baselines. One way to achieve this is to insert `^{}` (empty superscripts) in all terms that have a subscript.
- If you need Times Roman text and math fonts instead of the default (Computer/Latin Modern), be sure to load suitable packages that provide access to Times Roman text and math fonts.
- Last but not least, I'd use an `align` enviroment instead of three consecutive `equation` environments. If nothing else, using an `align` environment will let you align the three equations on their respective `=` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}      % for "align" environmenet
\usepackage{newtxtext}    % for Times Roman text font
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % for Times Roman math fonts
\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{3} % just for this example

\begin{align}
\nu^{}_{RZ} &= L\frac{di^{}_R}{dt} +Ri^{}_R +e^{}_R +\nu^{}_{XZ} \label{eq:4}\\
\nu^{}_{YZ} &= L\frac{di^{}_Y}{dt} +Ri^{}_Y +e^{}_Y +\nu^{}_{XZ} \label{eq:5}\\
\nu^{}_{BZ} &= L\frac{di^{}_B}{dt} +Ri^{}_B +e^{}_B +\nu^{}_{XZ} \label{eq:6}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

[image: good subscript and easy too]

As you will see the code is more straightforward too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cool}  % provides the easy derivative \D

\setcounter{equation}{3}  % gets us to the right equation number
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}    
    v_{RZ} = L \D{i_R}{t} + R i_R + e_R + v_{XZ}
    \label{eq:kvlA}  % use meaningful labeling rather than generic! 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}    
    v_{YZ} = L \D{i_Y}{t} + R i_Y + e_Y + v_{XZ}
    \label{eq:kvlB}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}    
    v_{BZ} = L \D{i_B}{t} + R i_B + e_B + v_{XZ}
    \label{eq:}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

LaTeX is made to typeset math, and it does a fine job without too much effort.

Comment: Using several `equation` environments in a row is not the best solution, try `align` (or even `gather`).